# How can I view multiple git diffs side by side in vim

Tags: git, vim, diff

I'd like to be able to run a command that opens up a git diff in vim, with a tab for each file in the diff set.

So if for example I've changed files foo.txt and bar.txt in my working tree and I ran the command I would see vim open with two tabs. The first tab would contain a side-by-side diff between foo.txt in my working tree and foo.txt in the repository, and the second tab would contain a side-by-side diff for bar.txt.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way I would do this (though it isn't a single command)

1. Open files with changes in new `vim` tabs:

   vim -p $(git diff --name-only)
2. For every buffer get the diff to your current HEAD with the [vcscommand vim plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=90)

   :VCSVimDiff

This gives a nice view of the difference, though not in patch form.

For anything else I would stick to `git diff`.

**EDIT**

Like Dave writes below, steps 1 and 2 can be combined by using

```
vim -p $(git diff --name-only) -c "tabdo VCSVimDiff"
```

Comment: You could possibly combine it into one command, which could be put into a shell script or function.  (untested code ahead):
vim -p $(git diff --name-only) -c "tabdo VCSVimDiff"

Comment: I tried both the one-liner and the 2 part commands. It only does the diff for the last tab opened. Other tabs have to have :VCSVimDiff called on them. Solutions?.. I'd love to get all of the tabs running diffs.

Comment: For diffs of many local files compared to a single reference file `gvim -p <file list> -c "tabdo vert diffsplit ref.log"`

Answer (score 8):

*Adapted Benjamin Bannier + Dave Kirby's answer above for fugitive users.*

Because I use fugitive.vim, I adapted the above for my most frequent use case, looking at the diff between the last 2 commits:

```
vim -p $(git diff --name-only HEAD~1 HEAD) -c "tabdo :Gdiff HEAD~1"
```

Loading all the changes into tabs is so much better than going through them sequentially with `git difftool`.

Comment: That is the answer I'm looking for, now I just need an alias then I'm done, thank you.

Answer (score 4):

Although it doesn't do exactly what you want, git difftool is probably your best bet.  The out of the box behavior of 'git difftool --tool=vimdiff --no-prompt HEAD' is to launch vimdiff sequentially for each file in the working dir with changes.

Comment: Very useful. All built into git and vim. No muss, no fuss.

Answer (score 2):

I came up with the following script to achieve the behaviour git difftoll + vimdiff provides, but using tabs:

```
#!/bin/bash

commit1=$1
commit2=$2

files=`git diff ${commit1} ${commit2} --name-only`

cmd="set nosplitright | set nobackup | set noswapfile"

EXE="| silent exe"

for f in $files; do
    if [ -z "$commit2" ]; then
        cmd+="$EXE ':tabnew $f'"
    else
        cmd+="$EXE ':tabnew | f <${commit2}>/${f} | setlocal buftype=nofile | 0read ! git show ${commit2}:$f'"
    fi
    cmd+="$EXE ':0 | filetype detect'"
    cmd+="$EXE ':vnew | f <${commit1}>/${f} | setlocal buftype=nofile | 0read ! git show ${commit1}:$f'"
    cmd+="$EXE ':0 | filetype detect'"
    cmd+="$EXE ':windo diffth'"
done
cmd+="$EXE 'bd 1 | tabfirst'"

vim -c "$cmd"
```

Call it like this:
`vimgd <commit1> <commit2>`

Answer (score 0):

This simple plugin has worked for me: [TabMultiDiff](http://www.xenomachina.com/2012/02/multi-diff-with-vim-andor-git.html). It basically creates a diff tab for each pair of files passed to vim. The tab is named after the second file in each pair.

Note it is not [plugin manager compatible](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/285/what-makes-a-plugin-vundle-compatible-and-are-other-plugin-managers-interchangea), so you need to manually install it by copying `tab-multi-diff.vim` to `.vim/plugin`.

Here is a screenshot of comparing two pairs of simple files (aaa/aab and aac/aad). Note that I also use [vim-scripts/diffchar.vim](https://github.com/vim-scripts/diffchar.vim) which is why individual characters are highlighted.
[image]